# Underscorejs 'find' not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I use the following code, in a nodejs app, to build a tree from an array of database rows that form an adjacency list:

```
// Lay out every node in the tree in one flat array.
var flatTree = [];
_.each(rows, function(row) {
    flatTree.push(row);
});

// For each node, find its parent and add it to that parent's children.
_.each(rows, function(row) {
    // var parent = _.find(flatTree, function(p) {
    //     p.Id == row.ParentId;
    // });
    var parent;
    for (var i = 0; i < flatTree.length; i++){
        if (flatTree[i].Id == row.ParentId) {
            parent = flatTree[i];
            break;
        }
    };
    if (parent){
        if (!parent.subItems) {
            parent.subItems = [];
        };
        parent.subItems.push(row);
    }
});
```

I expect the commented out `_.find` call to do exactly the same as what the work-around `for` loop below it does, but `_.find` never finds the parent node in `flatTree`, while the `for` loop always does.

Similarly, a call to `_.filter` just doesn't work either, while the substitute loop does:

```
// var rootItems = _.filter(flatTree, function (node) {
//     //node.ParentId === null;
//     node.NoParent === 1;
// })
var rootItems = [];
for (var i = 0; i < flatTree.length; i++){
    if (flatTree[i].ParentId == null){
        rootItems.push(flatTree[i]);
    }
}
```

I am using the `underscore-node` package, but have tried and had the same results with the regular `underscore` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just missed the `return`.

```
var parent = _.find(flatTree, function(p) {
    return p.Id == row.ParentId; // Return true if the ID matches
    ^^^^^^ <-- This
});
```

In your code nothing is returned, so by default `undefined` will be returned and `parent` will not contain any data.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I realised that shortly after asking the question, as I had translated in my mind from arrow function syntax, where the return is not needed. I'm too used to C# LINQ. But I left the question open to maybe help others, and give someone a chance to answer.